# Python multiprocessing TypeError: cannot pickle '_queue.SimpleQueue' object

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, multiprocessing, threadpool

all. I currently meet a question. What I want to do is run a socket server by multiprocessing package. But once I run the program, there is an error will be reported, saying,  `TypeError: cannot pickle '_queue.SimpleQueue' object`. I have no idea why this will happen. So, could anyone help me resolve it?

```
class xxx:
    ......
    def test_connect(self, max_num=10, alive=True, mode='TCP', IP='127.0.0.1', PORT=8080):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=self.create_tcp_server, )
        p.start()
        p.join()
    ......
```

If not, I have another question with `multi-thread` question,[image]

As the picture shows, I want to run `comac_connect` via thread pool and in the `comac_connect` it will call another function `message_handle` through the same thread pool. But the real situation is the function `message_handle` cannot be executed, and the program holds there. Is there any solution that I can resolve it?

Comment: Do you use the Queue object from the `multiprocessing` module ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but it will report the same error.

Comment: Have you tried some small working example ? Something like https://pastebin.com/HNTBRrMP